# MailGun: Privacy error when opening MailGun unsubscribe link

Tags: https, mailgun, mailgun-api

I have an automatic email that gets sent out and has the `%tag_unsubscribe_url%` in the html body. When I click on it takes me to `email.mg.domain.com`, but the page complains that the connection isn't private. [Your connection isn't private page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLZSZ.png)

I tried to change the link to `link.mailgun.com` as recommended in another forum/post but had no luck.

When I swap the MailGun credentials to my personal MailGun account everything works fine, and I can unsubscribe from the emails.

What allows the unsubscribe to work from my personal account and not my company's account?